# Ruby Program to solve Circular Primes below number x

Tags: ruby

I'm working on project [Euler #35](https://projecteuler.net/problem=35).  I am getting the wrong number returned and I can't find where I have done wrong!

```
  def is_prime?(num)
    (2..Math.sqrt(num)).each { |i| return false if num % i == 0}
    true
  end

  def is_circular?(num)
    len = num.to_s.length
    return true if len == 1
    (len - 1).times do
      new_n = cycle(num)
      break unless is_prime?(new_n)
    end
  end

  def cycle(num)
    ary = num.to_s.split("")
    return ary.rotate!.join.to_i
  end

  def how_many
    circulars = []
    (2..1000000).each do |num|
      if is_prime?(num) && is_circular?(num)
        circulars << num
      end
    end
    p circulars.count
  end

  how_many #=> 14426
```

The returned number is '14426'.  I am only returning the circular primes, supposedly the correct answer is '55'

Comment: I'm getting `1671` as the return value because you have one hundred thousand not a million in your code above. Please edit.

Comment: Good eye @sagarpandya82 I edited the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have edited your code with few fixes in Ruby way. Your mistake was including corect set of `[a, b, c]` three times to count, instead of counting them as a one circular prime number. Your answer was correct, while 55 is the number of unique sets.

```
require 'prime'

class Euler35
  def is_circular?(num)
    circulars_for(num).all?{ |el| ::Prime.instance.prime?(el) }
  end

  def circulars_for(a)
    a.to_s.split("").length.times.map{|el| a.to_s.split("").rotate(el).join.to_i }
  end

  def how_many
    circulars = []
    ::Prime.each(1_000_000) do |num|
      continue if circulars.include?(num)
      if is_circular?(num)
        circulars << circulars_for(num)
      end
    end
    circulars.count
  end
end

puts Euler35.new.how_many # => 55
```

Comment: What' s with the " ::Prime"  ? It works fine with just "Prime" . I did not even know this was valid syntax.

Comment: It should work, while I had error that Euler35 has no inner class Prime, which means namespaces conflict. `::` orders to start from root. I would prefer to avoid such direct commands if possible.